# Tomcat 7 start failed with srpingboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

I have a spring-boot app (Tomcat 7, Jdk 1.8, maven) that I try to run (It is not a embedded tomcat) and I got several issues like :

```
 Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at ep.OWebApplicationInitializer.main(OWebApplicationInitializer.java:14)
```

What's wrong ?
My class main :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OWebApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(OWebApplicationInitializer.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

And my pom like that :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Someone have idea with this issue ?

Comment: `AbstractMethodError` usually means you are executing (in the server) against different library version than the one you used when compiling.  In the library used for compiling the method was concrete, while in the server's library it is abstract.

Comment: Why are you excluding the tomcat dependency? Did you add your own?

Comment: Yes I add mine .. Tomcat 7 (mandatory for my projeect) .. but I use the last version of springboot ..may be it is the cause of issue ? <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched versions of your dependencies on the classpath.

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

And use Tomcat 8.

Comment: I have a pom parent where I defined it .. ´´<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>  .. I use for the moment tomcat  7

Comment: Please refer the System requirements :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html

Check Tomcat Requirements for Servlet versions :
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Thanks so much ... I use springboot 1.4.6 and my tomcat run now ... thxxxxx

Answer (score -1):

You can override SpringBootServletInitializer's configure:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(OWebApplicationInitializer.class);
}
```

Comment: Why would he do that? How does your answer solve the problem?